# How to create an aspect class that will implement the logging functionality

Tags: java, spring, aspect

How to create an aspect class that will implement the logging functionality. Logged classes/packages/methods need to be defined in the configuration file.

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Autowired
    private List<PackageProperties> packageProperties;

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.epam.operations.Operations.removeStudentFromList())")
    public void removeStudentLog() {

    }

    @After("removeStudentLog()")
    public void applicationLogger() {
        log.info("Student deleted");
    }
}
```

*application.properties*

```
remove.packageName = org.epam.operations
remove.className = Operations
remove.methodName = removeStudentFromList
add.packageName = org.epam.operations
add.className = Operations
add.methodName = addStudent
```

Answer (score 0):

For loading the value from properties file you have many ways, which mostly are different in initialization order in IOC container,  two of them are as follow

- Implement EnvironmentAware interface

```html
public class YourAspectClass implements EnvironmentAware {

    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

}
```

- Using of @Value annotation to access property .

```html
package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Value {
    String value();
}
```

```html
@Value("#{pointer_of_property}") String value
```